# Access VBA not working when already executed previously

Tags: vba, checkbox, textbox

I'm pretty new at VBA. I have a form with a text box and a check box.  If I open the form and click the check box without populating the text box, I get a message box to enter comments.

However, in the same session, if I unchecked the box and recheck it, I do not get the message box to enter comments even tho the text box is blank.

How can I get the code to "refire" in the same session to give me the message box to enter comments?

Below is my code:

```
Private Sub Check29_Click()

    If IsNull(Me.Text16) Then

        MsgBox "Comments are Required.", vbCritical
        Me.Check29 = Null
        Exit Sub

    Else

        If Me.Check29 = -1 Then

            Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
            Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Exclusions", dbOpenDynaset)
            RS.AddNew
            RS("HW535ID") = Me![HWID]
            RS("Excluded") = "Yes"
            RS("BOA Assignee") = Me![AssignedBA]
            RS("Comments") = Me![Text16]
            RS("CheckBox") = Me![Check29]
            RS("Date of Exclusion") = Me![Text115]
            RS("ReviewID") = Me![Text33]
            RS.Update
            RS.Close
            Set RS = Nothing
            Exit Sub

        Else

            DoCmd.SetWarnings False
            DoCmd.OpenQuery ("RemoveExclusion")
            Me.Text16 = Null
            Exit Sub

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Debug the code and inspect `Me.Text16.Value` the second time around. Something (another event?) must be setting the value to something other than null.

Comment: I think it would be better if you checked the length of the string (content) of Text16 since that is what appears to be critical. An "empty" text field is not necessarily equivalent to "null". Try, perhaps: `If Len(Me.Text16.Text) = 0 Then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see a logic problem in the code. Please be aware that this line:

```
  Me.Check29 = Null
```

will *re-trigger* the _click event and produce unexpected results. And it is also incorrect (should be Me.Check29.Value=False). Please try the revised version below:

Declare a module level variable

```
 Option Explicit
 Private bCancel as Boolean
```

The event code (I also made more corrections):

```
Private Sub Check29_Click()

if bCancel Then Exit Sub
bCancel = False

If Trim(Me.Text16.Text) = vbnullstring Then

    MsgBox "Comments are Required.", vbCritical
    bCancel = True
    Me.Check29.Value = False
    bCancel =  False
    Exit Sub

Else

    If Me.Check29.Value = True Then

        Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
        Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Exclusions", dbOpenDynaset)
        RS.AddNew
        RS("HW535ID") = Me![HWID]
        RS("Excluded") = "Yes"
        RS("BOA Assignee") = Me![AssignedBA]
        RS("Comments") = Me![Text16]
        RS("CheckBox") = Me![Check29]
        RS("Date of Exclusion") = Me![Text115]
        RS("ReviewID") = Me![Text33]
        RS.Update
        RS.Close
        Set RS = Nothing
        Exit Sub

    Else

        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.OpenQuery ("RemoveExclusion")
        Me.Text16.Text = vbnullstring
        Exit Sub

    End If

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: M.R. - thanks for that code...it looks like that will solve the issue but when I run it, I get an error that the text box doesn't have focus (You can't reference a property or method for a control unless the control has the focus). I think this is due to the .text in the (Me.Text16.Text). Also, probably a dumb question but where do I put the module level Option Explicit? When I add it, the debug is saying there needs to be an =.

Comment: Just add Me.Text16.SetFocus before you attempt to set the text.  Add  "Option Explicit + Private const bCancel as Boolean" just ABOVE all code in the module.

Comment: Or just skip 'Option Explicit' This enforces variable declaration. Just add Private Const bCancel as Boolean at the top of the module before any code

Comment: Ok, I got it working!  Thank you M.R.!  I owe you a beer :-)  I did find another scenario where if I removed the comments first and the unchecked the box, it didn't remove the record from the back-end database.  I made some modifications and it all works perfectly now.  Below is the final code!  Thanks to everyone who chimed it...its much appreciated and I definitely learned something about coding!

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub Check29_Click()

If bCancel Then Exit Sub
bCancel = False

Me.Text16.SetFocus

If Trim(Me.Text16.Text) = vbNullString And Me.Check29.Value = True Then

```
MsgBox "Comments are Required.", vbCritical
bCancel = True
Me.Check29.Value = False
bCancel = False
Exit Sub
```

Else

```
If Me.Check29.Value = True Then

    Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
    Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Exclusions", dbOpenDynaset)
    RS.AddNew
    RS("HW535ID") = Me![HWID]
    RS("Excluded") = "Yes"
    RS("BOA Assignee") = Me![AssignedBA]
    RS("Comments") = Me![Text16]
    RS("CheckBox") = Me![Check29]
    RS("Date of Exclusion") = Me![Text115]
    RS("ReviewID") = Me![Text33]
    RS.Update
    RS.Close
    Set RS = Nothing
    Exit Sub

Else
    If Me.Check29.Value = False Then

        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.OpenQuery ("RemoveExclusion")
        Me.Text16 = ""
    Exit Sub

    End If

End If
```

End If

End Sub